# Find the values $a$ and $b$ of this limit

Tags: calculus

> Find $a$ and $b$ such that,$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin(\frac {a \pi x}{2})}{x}\right)^{b/x^{2}} =\ 7$$

**My try:**

I applied L'Hospital's rule several times and ended up with an indeterminate form $0/0$, I did not succeed in finding the values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Please make an edit. And include your research effort.

Comment: i used texmarket for edit this question, i dont understand , why reason dont read the limit

Comment: Show us what you've done, at least a part of it. If you need some help with editing I can help. But it is not that hard to use MathJax, please make sure you check [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This limit have the form 0/0, i aplied the l Hopital rule , the limit have don't exists, why ?

Answer (score 1):

As a hint: use $\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-...\sim x-\frac{x^3}{3!} $ so $$sin(kx)\sim kx-\frac{k^3x^3}{3!}\\ \frac{sin(kx)}{x}\sim k- \frac{k^3x^2}{3!}\\$$ so $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin(\frac {a \pi x}{2})}{x}\right)^{\dfrac{b}{x^{2}}} $$

Answer (score 1):

*This is a different answer using only L'Hospital's rule*

Using L'Hospital's rule, one can easily show that,

$$\quad \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(kx)}{x} =k \quad (*)$$

As in the previous answer, we will use exponential form and look for,

$$\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} =  \dfrac{\ln \left(\frac{\sin(kx)}{x} \right)}{x^2} = \dfrac{\ln(\sin(kx))-\ln(x)}{x^2}$$

With $f: x \mapsto \ln \left(\frac{\sin(kx)}{x} \right)$ and $g : x \mapsto x^2$ and $k = \dfrac{a \pi}{2}$

Here, we are seeking for an inderminate form $0/0$ to **apply** l'Hospital's rule, hence we need that $f(x) \underset{x \to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0$, the only way to do that is that what is inside $\ln$ tends towards $1$, but using $(\ast)$ this imposes that $k=1$ hence,

$$\boxed{a = \dfrac{2}{\pi}}$$

First,

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}-\dfrac{1}{x}=\dfrac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x \sin(x)}$$

$$g'(x) = 2x$$

Hence,

$$\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\dfrac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{2x^2 \sin(x)} = \dfrac{h(x)}{d(x)}$$

Where $h : x \mapsto x \cos(x) -\sin(x)$ and $d : x \mapsto 2x^2 \sin(x)$

But as it is again an indeterminate form $0/0$ we will apply again l'Hospital's rule,

$$h'(x) = -x\sin(x)+\cos(x)-\cos(x)= -x\sin(x)$$

$$d'(x) = 4x\sin(x)+2x^2\cos(x)$$

Hence,

$$\dfrac{h'(x)}{d'(x)}=\dfrac{-x \sin(x)}{4x\sin(x)+2x^2\cos(x)}=\dfrac{-1}{4+2\dfrac{x}{\sin(x)} \cos(x)}$$

Therefore,

$$\dfrac{h'(x)}{d'(x)} \underset{x \to 0}{\rightarrow} \dfrac{-1}{4+2} = -\dfrac{1}{6}$$

Hence by applying l'Hospital's rule twice we have,

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{h'(x)}{d'(x)} = -\dfrac{1}{6}$$

---

Finally we have,

$$\left( \dfrac{\sin\left( \dfrac{a \pi}{2}\right)}{x}\right)^{b/x^2} = \exp\left( \dfrac{b}{x^2}\ln \left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right) \right) \underset{x \to 0}{\longrightarrow} \exp\left(- \dfrac{b}{6}\right)$$

And as we want this limit to be $7$ then we just need to choose,

$$\boxed{b=-6 \ln(7)}$$

---

We are happy to see that we have the same result as in my previous answer.

Comment: (+1) nicely done.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Thank you. I attempted here to meet the OP's expectations.

Comment: That's why I upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the exponential form,

$$\left(\frac{\sin(\frac {a \pi x}{2})}{x}\right)^{\frac{b}{x^{2}}} =\exp\left(\frac{b}{x^{2}} \ln \left(\frac{\sin(\frac {a \pi x}{2})}{x} \right) \right)$$

And now we'll work with

$$\frac{b}{x^{2}} \ln \left(\frac{\sin(\frac {a \pi x}{2})}{x} \right)$$
and we'll try to find conditions on $a$ and $b$ to have the desired limit.

---

We'll use Taylor expansion of $\sin$ at the order $3$.

$$\sin(x)=x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)$$

Hence by taking $k = \dfrac{a \pi}{2}$

$$\dfrac{\sin(kx)}{x} = k-k^3\dfrac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)$$

Therefore using $\ln(ab) = \ln(a)+\ln(b)$ and $\ln(1-x) =-x+o(x)$, we get,

$$\ln\left(\dfrac{\sin(kx)}{x}\right) = \ln(k)+\ln\left(1-k^2\dfrac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)\right) = \ln(k)-k^2\dfrac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)$$

Hence,

$$\dfrac{b}{x^2} \ln\left(\dfrac{\sin(kx)}{x}\right)=\dfrac{b}{x^2}\ln(k)-k^2\dfrac{b}{6}+o(1) $$

To have a finite limit, we'll take $k=1$ to have $\ln(k)=0$ therefore it means we take $a = \dfrac{2}{\pi}$.

Now we want,

$$e^{-b/6}=7$$

So we just need to take,

$$b =-6\ln(7)$$

Comment: Thanks By the problem is,  i don't can used Taylor

Comment: @MariaLinder Ok. At least do you know the exponential form, i.e. $a^b = e^{b \ln a} $ for $a>0$?

Comment: That yes, is propiety of the l' hopital

Comment: @MariaLinder Sorry but I hardly see how you could use L'hospital's rule efficiently. Are you forced to use this rule?

Comment: Yes, because only with that method the teacher teach

Comment: I do not like much this rule. Anyway what did you try? I'll try to think about it but I'll not guarantee you another answer.

Comment: I usted the exponential method, but don't finish this exercise, and the other method is aplied form 0/0.

Comment: Axel thanks you so much

Comment: @MariaLinder You're welcome. I'm glad I could help!